# After a war that killed a generation of men, what happens to that nation?

Tags: society, warfare, culture

In my world a nation has lost every man between the ages of 18-40 to war. What possible impacts on society from such a loss of life would I need to consider?

Comment: **All** the young men?  That means they lost the war, and the victors will come in and take over.

Comment: You might look into what happened to Paraguay when it suffered [a similar situation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraguayan_War#Casualties_of_the_war).

Comment: Of course the outcome of the war matters.  And you should research Europe after the Great War.

Comment: @RonJohn's right.  Before WWI and WWII there were very few women in the workforce.  Despite not suffering anywhere near the losses you're suggesting, the entirety of western culture shifted to allow women in the workforce, which required an incredibly complex stabilization of economies due to what would be an overabundance of workers once the wars ended and the men returned home.  Regrettably, an analysis on that scale isn't just a book-length dissertation - it's a fair number of volumes.

Comment: Look up the population pyramids for the WWI generations in Germany and France to see that there were still plenty of young males after the war. Turns out lots of young people are unsuitable for military service, or find employment in war-critical industries, or find other ways to avoid it.

Comment: expect more single mothers, and higher tolerance of men cheating on their wives :)

Comment: Since there are multiple real life examples (Paraguay, France/Germany after WWI, Germany/Russia WWII), this should be answerable. A good answer would summarize similarities between the aforementioned cases. So I vote to re-open.

Comment: Well the population would rebound in one generation, because the bottleneck on procreation is women, not men. You would expect the few men around to sleep with basically many many women. Either cheating would be widespread and accepted, or you would have men with many many wives. Men would probably be very young (15-17) or very old, but either way men would be a sought after part of society with high competition for them and maybe sexual abuse by women on young men. Women would also have to enter the workforce to pick up all the slack left by the fallen men.

Comment: @kingledion -- Answerable? Sure, the query is answerable. It's a fill in the blank of answerability; and there's no criteria for judging the answer! The spectrum of possible & good answers is so broad we can't even see from one end to the other. Keep it closed until it's a bit more focused.

Comment: It is now answerable (certainly with respect to other questions) all that he is asking for is a list of plausible impacts to society that occur from the loss of so many men. There are plenty of historical sources than can be drawn upon. As with all answers the best well researched answer should win.

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper I think there's more to it than the question of whether population would rebound.  For one thing, you're either going to have polygamy (as you suggest), or lots of elderly men marrying young women, or simply many, many unmarried women with no children.  Then, you're going to have a younger generation with a serious shortage of male role models.  Finally, this small younger generation will have a huge burden caring for a large elderly generation.  Any of these changes could have huge effects on the culture which might last for a long time.